# how can update part of the value in SQL

Tags: sql-server

i have this sample:

i wanted to change the value of '&' into 'C:\' having trouble composing a script.
[image]

Comment: It's important to show the things you've attempted in order for us to help. Essentially if you show what you've tried one of us can look at it, explain what you're doing wrong and help you fix it. As written it's just a "do this for me" request and we don't do that here.

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: look for `replace` - first do a `select` to see how the data with `replace` will look like and once you are happy, write an update query to actually update the records.

Comment: @kin I would avoid replace in this instance unless the OP is certain that the only place that & appears is in the first character.

Comment: @JonathanFite I guessed based on the image in the question which has `&` at the beginning. There are much better ways to do this :-)

Answer (score 0):

This example should be enough to get you started.  I would avoid REPLACE in this scenario because you want to only replace the first instance of "&", not all of them (probably).

```
DECLARE @Files AS TABLE
    (
    [filename] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    , autoname CHAR(1) NOT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO @Files
([filename], autoname)
VALUES ('&test me.doc', 'Y')
    , ('no change.doc', 'Y')
    , ('not & this.doc', 'Y')

UPDATE @Files
SET [filename] = CASE WHEN LEFT([filename], 1) = '&' THEN 'C:\' + RIGHT([filename], LEN([filename]) - 1)
                        ELSE [filename]
                        END
WHERE [filename] LIKE '&%'

SELECT * FROM @Files
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use DATABASENAME

select * from dbo.document
where filename like '\\LAWSVR\Law Firm\%'
```

Backed up the database. Ran this script:

```
update dbo.document
set filename = REPLACE(filename, '\\LAWSVR\Law Firm\', 'K:\')
where filename like '\\LAWSVR\Law Firm\%'
```

This seems to work